# Excel to access multiple spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Heres my question.

Lets assume we have 3 employees: Bobby, juliet, and sue.One supervisor, named Kelly is at her desk and Shiela, the president, is waiting for an email.

Bobby, Juliet, and Sue are using Excel 2010 to enter customer information into a Workbook named "Data Entry". Each record they enter, is tallied automatically and displayed in selected cells within the form. Juliet may have entered 3 records within the last hour, and Sue may have had 5, or 6, etc..

Every 3 hours or so, Kelly has to get up, walk to each persons desk, and ask them how many customers they have entered at that particular time. Kelly has to tally up all three of those customer totals, and then go back to her desk and enter them into an email, to be sent to Shiela, the president, so that she can see, in real time, what the current results are for the day.

I want to make a link between three *or more* individual Work books, and Access, such that when Sue or Juliet or Bobby enters a customer record, the tallied fields, or even the record itself, is updated in the access database at Kelly's desk. That way, Kelly can query Access for a total from all worksheets, and email her boss without having to get up and walk around. Also, I would like it so that Sue and Bobby and Juliet can use a new( fresh form),each morning, when they arrive at work, but have it linked when they start excel automatically.

I was able to successfully create the link between one workbook and database, and it populates the info perfectly, however, i need this to happen with multiple excel files ..in real time..if anyone can help thank you so much.!

Comment: Excel is really not going to handle this very well. Have you considered something like Google Docs Spreadsheet?

Comment: What you describe is a database application, not a spreadsheet solution. Why don't you use Access for the data entry in the first place instead of routing it through spreadsheets? Access can do all things you describe.

Comment: Thank you Both for your prompt responses..as I am at work, my responses are delayed..My apologies. The reason I cannot use access for entry( and believe me i want thAT ) is because all of the empooyees do not have it on their computers. I gave an example of 3 people, but actually there are 65-80. So Its not possible for me, as a reg employee( trying to help my dept.) to authorize installation of access for that many people.

Answer (score 3):

> The reason I cannot use access for entry( and believe me i want thAT ) is because all of the empooyees do not have it on their computers. I gave an example of 3 people, but actually there are 65-80. So Its not possible for me, as a reg employee( trying to help my dept.) to authorize installation of access for that many people. –  user3093221 59 mins ago

I understand your predicament. What you want is absolutely **possible**. And I am saying **this** from experience.

Many years ago, when I was working as an Operations Manager for a **BPO**, we faced the same problem. Besides **Operations**, I was also responsible for the **MIS** team. Unfortunately the company didn't have enough license for MS-Access. I was playing more of Shiela's role-play. Whether you want to believe it or not, my friends in that company tell me that they are still using that system that I created many years ago.

**What You Need To Do**

1. Save your Working Excel file as a read-only Excel file.
2. Distribute the Read-Only Excel File to 60-80 people.
3. Keep the Access database at a centralized location. You don't need license for this. Ensure that Excel file refers to the database with the correct Network Path.
4. Create one more file for `Kelly` which can read data from the database. This file will again be a Read-Only File and can be used to view and create reports

Now for points 2 and 3, you will definitely need IT Dept's help.

And you are done.

Comment: OMG Siddharth you absolutely rock sir..!! im going to try this today..ill get back with you ..let you know how it goes!! thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ok im having a little trouble figuring how a read only document, can have new elements added daily , by the employees? If it is read-only, how can they enter iformation. Plus i cannot find the function for read only..thanks again!

Comment: The excel file is readonly so that you cannot make any changes to it and save it. You can however add data to it say in userforms which ultimately will push that data in the database.To make the file readonly, see [This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/make-a-document-read-only-HA010152719.aspx#_Toc288629967)